# How to export the entire datagridview into a word document (using office word interop DLL in C#)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

How to update/write/save/export the entire DataTable or datagridview into a same word document(Several times) using office word interop DLL?iam able to achieve it but the thing is i cant save DataTable into a single document , evertime it saves as new document wont save in a previous document. 
    `using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq; 
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;
    using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
    using System.Reflection;

```
namespace Save_DataTable
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string data_path;
    public string File_path;
    public string filename;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("x",            
   typeof(int)), new DataColumn("y", typeof(string)), new   
   DataColumn("z",  
   typeof(string)) });
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "1", "1");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "2", "2");
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "3", "3");
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "4", "4");
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void Save()
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            int RowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            int ColumnCount = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
            Object[,] DataArray = new object[RowCount + 1, ColumnCount 
       + 
        1];

            //add rows
            int r = 0;
            for (int c = 0; c <= ColumnCount - 1; c++)
            {
                for (r = 0; r <= RowCount - 1; r++)
                {
                    DataArray[r, c] = 
       dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value;
                } //end row loop
            } //end column loop

            Word.Document oDoc = new Word.Document();
            //oDoc.Application.Visible = false;

            Word.Application app = new Word.Application();

            app.Application.Visible = false;

            try
            {
                oDoc = app.Documents.Open(filename);

            }
            catch
            {
            }
            //page orintation
            oDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = 
          Word.WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;


            dynamic oRange = oDoc.Content.Application.Selection.Range;
            string oTemp = "";
            for (r = 0; r <= RowCount - 1; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c <= ColumnCount - 1; c++)
                {
                    oTemp = oTemp + DataArray[r, c] + "\t";

                }
            }

            //table format
            oRange.Text = oTemp;

            object Separator =  
         Word.WdTableFieldSeparator.wdSeparateByTabs;
            object ApplyBorders = true;
            object AutoFit = true;
            object AutoFitBehavior = 
         Word.WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitContent;

            oRange.ConvertToTable(ref Separator, ref RowCount, ref 
            ColumnCount,
                                  Type.Missing, Type.Missing, ref 
             ApplyBorders,
                                  Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
             Type.Missing,
                                  Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
              Type.Missing,
                                  Type.Missing, ref AutoFit, ref 
              AutoFitBehavior, Type.Missing);

            oRange.Select();

            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Select();


        oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows.AllowBreakAcrossPages 
        = 0;
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows.Alignment = 0;
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Select();
            oDoc.Application.Selection.InsertRowsAbove(1);
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Select();

            //header row style
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Range.Bold = 
            1;

           oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Range.Font.Name 
           = "Tahoma";

          oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Range.Font.Size 
         = 14;

            //add header row manually
            for (int c = 0; c <= ColumnCount - 1; c++)
            {
                oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Cell(1, c + 
       1).Range.Text = dataGridView1.Columns[c].HeaderText;
            }

            //table style
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].set_Style("Grid Table 
        4 - Accent 5");
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Select();
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Cells.VerticalAlignment = 
          Word.WdCellVerticalAlignment.wdCellAlignVerticalCenter;

            //header text
            foreach (Word.Section section in 
         oDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Sections)
            {
                Word.Range headerRange = 
         section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.
                      wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
                headerRange.Fields.Add(headerRange, 
            Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage);
                headerRange.Text = "Header Text";
                headerRange.Font.Size = 16;
                headerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment =  
            Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
            }
            oDoc.Activate();
            filename = @"D:\\Save.docx";
            oDoc.SaveAs2(filename);
            oDoc.Close();
            app.Quit();
        }
         }
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        Save();
      }
       }
          }`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the Open XML SDK for generating Word documents (open XML documents) on the fly based on your data grid view. See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information.

Automating Word from other applications may take more time and has the following restriction:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.
>
> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article.